# access version specific value from within Rails app running on Heroku Ceder Stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, browser-cache, cedar

I have a Rails 4 app running on the Ceder Stack of Heroku.  I use conditional responses based on etag.  I have an initialization script which changes the etag value so that each new release requires browser to renew cache:

```
# creates new seed for creation of etag in header
ENV["RAILS_CACHE_ID"] = Time.now.to_s
```

This works fine in staging, but in production I am using multiple dynos and they can end up with different values.

Is there a variable I can use that will be unique for each release but identical across all dynos?  The git version number perhaps?  Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: Would something like this work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14899264/1807403

Comment: @JonathanBender-  Thanks for response.  I tried that and got:  2014-02-23T19:35:16.670333+00:00 app[web.1]: fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
I looked for a way to reference the git binary directly but didn't come up with anything.  Am I correct in assuming that any command in backticks is the same as when I enter it using:  heroku run console?

Comment: That would have been my assumption as well, though I've never done it. Another solution might be this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14924922/1807403, which seems to be a little more heroku-specific.